# How do I fix the highlighting when using Angular in VSCode

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

[image: What the code looks like in VSCode]

This is what it currently looks like. I read that VSCode works great with Angular but that doesn't seem to be the case for me when I'm using things like *ngFor and [ngClass].

So far I haven't been able to find any fix for this. I've looked through several plugins for VSCode but without success.

[edit]

It is supposed to recognise the typescript/js inside the quotes of *ngFor instead of just marking it as a regular string.

Comment: How do you think it *should* look?

Comment: could you be more clear? I don't understand the question.

Comment: Try this plugin https://github.com/angular/vscode-ng-language-service